# IOS: How to make tableview or label take up no space when empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

This would be easy in css or html but having hard time in IOS.

Is there a way to make a label or tableview take up no space when empty?

There seem to be lots of ways to make them hidden or make the label or textview small, but empty space always remains.

For example, the following code, if you disable auto layout, shrinks a label to the size of the text which in this case is nothing.  However, it leaves white space where the old tableview was so label3 does not follow label1 directly but rather they are separated by a bunch of white space.

```
//in view did load
self.label1.text = @"LOTS OF TEXT LOTS OF TEXT LOTS OF TEXT
self.label2.text=@"";
self.label2.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.label2 sizeToFit];
self.label3.text = @"LOTS OF TEXT LOTS OF TEXT LOTS OF TEXT";
```

I want the whole space taken up by label2 to shrink so that label 3 moves up.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `UITableView`, just return 0 for that particular row in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

For a standard `UILabel`, you'll have to set its height to 0 via a constraint.

Comment: This is not a tableview.  This is for a bunch of stacked labels and textfields in a UIView.  Some are empty so I would like them to disappear and the ones below to move up.  Can't use stack view as supporting  IOS 7,0 and above

Comment: How do you set height to 0 via a constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You could add labels programmatically, and then delete them if not used. Or add programmatically constraints, which would shrink when needed, hiding the labels if you're going to reuse them.

Comment: Is there a way to condition their location on the label above them?  Don't you have to do something like  UILabel *mylabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 50, 50)]; setting the location?

Comment: No, AutoLayout calculates all the frames. When you setup a constraint you put in the relative positions, for example `[_internalScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:FirstItem
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem: SecondItem
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:100.0]] `

Comment: you add the constraint to the parent view, internalScrollView?

Comment: @user5808042  show me the code with internalScrollView